# Samba fileshare accessible from certain Windows user

Tags: permissions, samba, windows-10

I'm using VirtualBox to run Ubuntu Desktop 16.04. I shared folder and can access it from any Windows user, but I really want so only one specific user can access it and others will get denied. I know how to set password to that share but that's not it. 
I tried to search similar question all day but without results. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand this part of your post:

`I know how to set password to that share but that's not it.`

It's not clear to me how one sets a password to a share.

Anyway, the classic way of doing this is to edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf` and create a share definition that in its simplest form looks something like this:

```
[ShareName]
path = /path/to/folder
read only = no
valid users = bob
```

Then restart smbd: `sudo service smbd restart`

You would have to:

** Create a local user on the Ubuntu box named: bob

** Then add him to the samba password database: `sudo smbpasswd -a bob`

Note: If you created the shares from Nautilus ( Files ) you need to go back and unshare it in Nautilus. Nautilus as currently configured does not have the ability to specify only one user for access.